# Storing two List<strings> into the properties of a collection object issue c#

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, list, collections

Hi I am trying to store two List that have been populated already, into collection objects, the collection is named "SpecialOffers" and I require the first string list to be set as one of the properties and the other string list as the other, however I am having issues inserting these lists into the collection to create new SpecialOffers objects in the collection. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NEW
I am scraping html content off a webpage, and trying to store the content in a collection defined using the SpecialOffers model seen below, both properties values are first stored in 2 string lists, 1 for the image property and 1 for the body property, I would then like to then insert these two lists as the values for the properties in the SpecialOffers collection.

**Model Class (SpecialOffers):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace RedSeaExample.Models
{
    public class SpecialOffers
    {
        public SpecialOffers(string image, string body)
        {
            this.image = image; ;
            this.body = body;
        }
               public string image { get; set; }
               public string body {get; set;}

     }
}
**Class to retrieve image sources and table html source**

public Collection<Models.SpecialOffers> captureLinks(string source, Collection<Models.SpecialOffers> specialOffersCollection, HtmlDocument html)
            {
                 int i = 0;
                 List<string> bodyList = new List<string>();
                 List<string> getString = new List<string>();

                List<List<string>> table1 = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]").Descendants("tr").Skip(1).Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() > 1).
                Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList()).ToList();

                 var table = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[1]").FirstOrDefault();


                         foreach (List<string> txt in table1)
                         {
                             foreach (string example in txt)
                             {                        
                                getString.Add(example + (i + 1).ToString());


                             }
                             bodyList.AddRange(table.SelectNodes("..//img/@src").Select(t => t.OuterHtml + (i + 1).ToString()));

                             specialOffersCollection.Add(bodyList);
                                 //(new SpecialOffers(bodyList.ToString(), getString.ToString()));
                         }


                         return specialOffersCollection;



            }
```

Comment: when you post code @Rob can you please do the following 
show all relevant code and or declarations of objects / variables and do not post partial code .. are you familiar with how to create a List<T> load it and loop through it..? if not here is a good link that can help you http://www.dotnetperls.com/list and perhaps `specialOffersCollection` should be a class and then from there you should perhaps create a List<specialOffersCollection> being a class that is

Comment: You need to include full code that replicates the issue, mostly the issue is not showing what types are: table1, getString, bodyList, specialOffersCollection. Also, it isn't really clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?  We can't debug this for you.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How can I insert two string lists, into a specialOffersCollection object to set the properties, image and body

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish, but you can construct a list of special offers from parallel lists using `.Zip()`.

```
specialOffersCollection.AddRange(
    bodyList.Zip(getString, (b, g) => new SpecialOffers(b, g));
```